# How to slide UIViewcontroller on a button even from bottom to top like an action sheet?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I am making an iPhone application. I want to slide a view controller on a button event from bottom to top just like action sheet. Can anyone please suggest me some code or sample for this? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to slide a `UIView` from bottom to top:

```
 myViewController *obj = [[myViewController alloc] init];
 [self presentModalViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

and the code below to slide a `UIView` from top to bottom, i.e., to dismiss the `UIView`:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical slides a view up from the bottom of the screen. On dismissal, the view slides back down.